# target an XML Node to change value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file as follows :-

```
<Root>
   <Player>
      <name>Name</name>
      <surname>Surname</surname>
      <rating>10</rating>
   </Player>
   <Player>
      <name>Name1</name>
      <surname>Surname1</surname>
      <rating>20</rating>
   </Player>
</Root>
```

Now I wish to target one of these nodes so that I can do some changes to it.

I have the following code :-

```
                XElement playerXML =
                doc.Root.Elements("Player").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("name").ToString() == playerInput.name
                                                                && x.Element("surname").ToString() == playerInput.surname
                                                                && Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("rating"))  == playerInput.rating);
            if (playerXML != null)
            {
                //do processing
            }
```

However I am not getting anything back, even though the name, surname and rating are in the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: May not be the problem, but do you have any particular reason to use `ToString()` instead of `Value` or [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319.aspx) (like `(int)(x.Element("rating"))` ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`XElement/XNode.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) *returns the XML including the element tags*.

Instead, use [`XElement.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) to "[get] the concatenated text contents of this element".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XElement.Value` Property instead of calling `ToString()` method.

```
doc.Root.Elements("Player").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("name").Value == playerInput.name
                                                                && x.Element("surname").Value == playerInput.surname
                                                                && Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("rating").Value) == playerInput.rating);
```